# Cannot put event to a cloud watch log stream using aws-sdk with serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to log some information to a log stream I created in aws watchlog using a lambda function with aws-sdk, but I cannot get any logs even when the lambda is triggered.

This is my code,

Triggering Lambda Code

```
...
const lambda = new aws.Lambda();
  lambda.invoke({
    FunctionName: 'email-api-dev-logError',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(err)
  }, (err, data) => {
    if(err) console.log('Lambda error is ', err);
    else console.log('Lambda Data is ', data);
  })
...
```

Lambda function

```
module.exports.logError = async (event) => {
  const cloudwatchlogs = new aws.CloudWatchLogs();

  const logEventParams = {
    logEvents: [
      {
        message: event,
        timestamp: new Date().getTime()
      }
    ],
    logGroupName: 'EmailAPIErrors',
    logStreamName: 'Error'
  };

  cloudwatchlogs.putLogEvents(logEventParams, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else console.log('Log data is ', data);
  });

};
```

serverless.yml

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
      Resource: "*"

    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sqs:SendMessage"
        - "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      Resource: "arn:aws:sqs:${self:provider.region}:*:EmailQueueDev"

    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "logs:CreateLogStream"
        - "logs:PutLogEvents"
      Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/rds/*:log-stream:*"
functions:
  logError:
    handler: handler.logError
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here, pls help me to find the possible error and the fix for it.

Comment: can you share your screenshots of lambda function screen

Comment: are you asking about the calling lambda? becuase the above is the entire lambda function for the logging purpose

Comment: I am asking about triggers and resources and IAM Role

Comment: Trigger is a lamda call from another lambda, and it's working fine, normal console logs print in the lambda's logGroup, and have updated the code aswell,

Comment: It looks like your role in `serverless.yml` is incorrectly defined. It refers to a log group `/aws/rds/*` which is completely wrong (default log group should be `/aws/lambda/*`), and it doesn't mention your `EmailAPIErrors` log group at all.

Comment: @kdgregory I changed the resource url to this, `arn:aws:logs:${self:provider.region}:${file(./config.js):log.account_id}:log-group:EmailAPIErrors:*`
still not logging

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to custom log-group from `AWS lambda`. The default log-group associated with lambda will be at `/aws/lambda/function-name.`

This is how the AWS lambda is designed. AWS Lambda service is kind of convention over configuration. So, the default log stream pattern is already defined.

You can do similar behavior if you happen to use `EC2` machine by installing `cloudwatch` agent on machine.

[cloudwatch agent configuration-EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html)

Comment: "You can't write to custom log-group from AWS lambda" -- really? Because I do it all the time.

Comment: @kdgregory As per the current AWS version, we also tried to specify custom log group, but it doesn't log to that group. May be if you have better solution, Kindly post the same.